# Postgres spring jpa column with uppercase error

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

My POSTGRESQL table column in Uppercase and in entity i mentioned colume name with uppercase using @column but it gives error as column doesnt exists ? Posgress doesn't support @column with uppercase value

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: Postgres knows nothing about @column syntax - it does not exist. If your obscurification language (spring) does not put the column in double quotes (") then Postgres [folds it to lower case](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html). See post by 
a_horse_with_no_name.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
@Column(name="`MYUPCASECOLUMN`")
```

Important is the `-charcter.

Answer (score 0):

Identifiers (including column names) that are not double-quoted are folded to lowercase in PostgreSQL. Column names that were created with double-quotes and thereby retained uppercase letters (and/or other syntax violations) have to be double-quoted for the rest of their life:

```
"first_Name"
```

Values (string literals / constants) are enclosed in single quotes:

```
'xyz'
```

You can also check this [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

I hope, it helps!